# Javascript client & asp.net server user authentification via session

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

I have a javascript client and an asp.net server. I am using simplemembership provider style authentification, the login/register and roles are working fine. The problem is, once the user logs in, I have to be able to check the future server controller hits and determine whether to permit or deny the user to use those controller functions. My first thought was using sessions, once the user logs in I would have the created session store his username (or id or whatever), and use that later to check whether his role has sufficient rights. The problem occurs when the log in function is hit, the session is created and the credentials are stored, but as soon as the function ends the session ends (which means I can't check his future controller hits). My question is, is there a way to makes this work this way (lets  say somehow forcing the session to stay open until logout or timeout), or am I going about it completely wrong?

Thank you in advance, and I hope this isn't one of those "stupid" questions!

Comment: The asp.net MVC has out of the box functionality which allows you to select which controllers/methods can be accessed by which users/roles. Have you tried this?

Comment: This would be the template generated by an empty MVC Internet application I assume? Using the [Authorize] attribute. I took that generated code and applied it to my case (minor changes). I also tried creating my own authorize attribute, yet the function decorated with it still does not even call that class. After some further inspection, I see that immediately after the WebSecurity.Login (which passes), User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false. Im getting the feeling I'm using something wrong.. I know this is a wide field to locate the error and thank you for any help or advice!

Comment: From what you wrote there is obviously something wrong with authentication, you have to investigate the process and look for any error that occurred

Comment: I have found a "sort of" solution by using Session state mode = SqlServer. Here I ran into more problems, mainly that no attempt was made to access the database to store session data. For some unknown reason, after many hours, I tried setting cookieless = true in my web config, and now the session data is stored correctly. I don't know whether this is a .net bug or what but it is a quite elusive and frustrating one.